# update music track play count in mysql with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i have a small script that already uses ajax to get a playlist of songs listed in a

list, it searches for the  and plays through the list

but i also want to have it update my database when the song starts playing

mySQL table:

**tbl_tracks:**

```
id | track_name | album_id | track_play_count | track_like_count
1    some song      12             3                    1
2    some song      13             9                    4
```

this is my ajax code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var audio;
    var playlist;
    var tracks;
    var current;
    //      $('.Mp3Link').click(); this will click something upon entry
    init();

    function init() {
        current = 0;
        audio = $('audio');
        playlist = $('#playlist');
        tracks = playlist.find('li a');
        len = tracks.length - 1;
        audio[0].volume = 1;
        audio[0].play();
        playlist.find('a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            link = $(this);
            current = link.parent().index();
            run(link, audio[0]);
        });
        audio[0].addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
            $('.lSNext').click();
            current++;
            if (current == len) {
                current = 0;
                link = playlist.find('a')[0];
            } else {
                link = playlist.find('a')[current];
            }
            run($(link), audio[0]);
        });
    }

    function run(link, player) {
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();

    }
});
```

so how can i have it update the **track_play_count** each time it starts a new song?

Thank you so very much in advance

Comment: In your `run` function call `AJAX` to update the counter.

Comment: And write a little PHP script to accept the parameter from the AJAX call and amend the database accordingly

Comment: But as you dont seem to have attempted anything like that in your code I suggest you do a little research and have a go at it, then come back with a specific issue if you have problems. Otherwise this is looking like a **do it for me** question

Comment: @RiggsFolly

there are people on stack overflow who are nice enough to code things out and share there knowledge by example, and i will take your suggestion to do more research (which is why i posted here in the first place), because I'm not entirely sure where to start from, a good link or another similar post answering this question would be nice